# Unity script not disabling after disabling gameobject attached to

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I have a GameObject (HandGun) which I disable (setActive(false)) in a certain moment of the game. HandGun has a script attached to it named GunController, which takes care of shooting everytime I press the trigger.

The thing is, when I disable the HandGun, I can still shoot and see the bullet coming out of nothing, because the HandGun GameObject is successfully gone.

GunController script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using EZEffects;
public class GunController : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject controllerRight;
public AudioClip clip;
AudioSource sound;
public int damage;
private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;
public SteamVR_Controller.Device device;

private SteamVR_TrackedController controller;

public EffectTracer TracerEffect;
public EffectImpact ImpactEffect;
public Transform muzzleTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sound = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    controller = controllerRight.GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedController>();
    controller.TriggerClicked += TriggerPressed;
    trackedObj = controllerRight.GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
    device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);
}

private void TriggerPressed(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    shootWeapon();
}

public void shootWeapon()
{
    sound.PlayOneShot(clip,0.2f);
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Ray ray = new Ray(muzzleTransform.position, muzzleTransform.forward);
    device.TriggerHapticPulse(3999);



    TracerEffect.ShowTracerEffect(muzzleTransform.position, muzzleTransform.forward, 250f);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5000f))
    {
        if (hit.collider.attachedRigidbody)
        {
            Enemy enemy = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
            if (enemy)
            {
                enemy.TakeDamage(damage);


            }
            ImpactEffect.ShowImpactEffect(hit.transform.position);
        }
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Part of the Inspector script, which is who disables the HandGun gameobject:

```cs
public void showShop()
{
    shop.SetActive(true);
    shopActive = true;
    if (actualGun == null)
    {
        actualGun = handGun;
    }
    actualGun.SetActive(false);
    model.SetActive(true);
}
```

Moreover, if I deactivate the GunController script manually when the game is running, I can still shoot, which I absolutely don't understand. I'm using EZEffect which can be found on the unity store.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Anyway, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could it be that you have attached the GunController script on multiple objects and therefor do not disable the desired object? Else it is quite weird what you describe does not work.

Comment: I've just double checked if there was in any other GameObject, but no, it's just in the HandGun... It's quite weird.
If we can't find any solution before tomorrow I'll just discard EzEffects and make my own script for shooting weapons. Anyway, thank you very much for you comment and help, sonny!

Comment: Can you show (the relevant) scene hierarchy and which object the script is attached to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script can still execute code when it is on a disabled gameobject.

However the Update Function will not fire.
Seeing as your GunController does not utilize its Update(), I suspect that your Input Listener is somewhere else (Probably EZEffect?).

To prevent your controller from firing, you could add a check to your code.

```
private void TriggerPressed(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (gameobject.ActiveSelf)
    {
        shootWeapon();
    }        
}
```

Or you can disable the script listening for User Input

Answer (score 0):

Inactive components will not call MonoBehavior derived methods like Start(), Update() etc. However, you can still call methods of scripts belonging to inactive gameobjects.

You can add/remove event handlers when the object becomes active/inactive by adding OnEnable/Disable methods to GunController:

```
void OnEnable() {
    controller.TriggerClicked += TriggerPressed;
}

void OnDisable() {
    controller.TriggerClicked -= TriggerPressed;
}
```